# Getting a "o is not a function" error only when doing a production build in vue 2.7.14

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, vuejs2, laravel-5.7

I'm working on a Laravel 5.7 project that has been through a few different developers.  Recently one of the devs did an npm update that caused a few issues.  I've got most all of those issues cleaned up, but now we are seeing an "o is not a function" error any time we try and access a variable in a vue component.  This issue only shows up after an npm run prod.  If we do an npm run dev everything works fine and the site looks perfect.

This has been a nightmare to debug since it only shows up in the minified production build.  I've tried using a few different versions of npm and some different minor releases of vue.  I know it's happening whenever we access a variable because I removed everything except for a @{{ status }} call inside of the component.  Without that I get no error and with it I get that "o is not a function" error.

Here are the dependencies in our `package.json`:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.1.14",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "vue": "^2.7.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.14"
},
"dependencies": {
    "axios-retry": "^3.1.2",
    "codemirror": "^5.65.10",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "inputmask": "^4.0.8",
    "mjml": "^4.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "npm": "^6.11.2",
    "signature_pad": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
    "spectrum-colorpicker": "^1.8.0",
    "vue-ckeditor2": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-markdown": "^2.2.4",
    "vue-simplemde": "^1.1.2",
    "vue2-dropzone": "^3.6.0",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.6.2",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
}
```

Comment: Why not rollback the update if it's such a pain?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there was a library added that needs the newer version of Vue.  My next step will be to start removing those libraries and rolling back, but obviously fixing the issue would be better.

Comment: Could also break more things down the road, you cannot be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem, so what i did is removing vue-bootstap package

> if you changed or updated version of laravel-mix or wabpack restore the inial ones

Comment: Don't you need it?